# Tailwindcss intellisense in vscode not working

Tags: tailwind-css

Tailwind intellisense in VSCode is not working when I'm using it with tailwindcss "Play CDN".
Is there any solution or any other extention that can help me.

Answer (score 29):

This is a kind of work around:

Just create a file `tailwind.config.js` in root directory of project. And it will work as charm.

Even if there is no content inside the file, the Tailwind intellisense will work while using Play CDN of tailwind.

Comment: Just creating a file won't work. The contents of the file should be at least: 
`module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js}'],
  theme: {},
};
`

Comment: @Brampage actually seems to work with an empty file (VSCode v1.81.1, Tailwind CSS IntelliSense v0.9.13, Microsoft Windows 11 Pro)

Answer (score 1):

Create the file "tailwind.config.js" in the root directory worked!

Answer (score -1):

Try to invalidate cache / remove node modules and yarn/npm your project again.